# How to access / modify DOM elements in Chrome Extension Manifest V3 content script?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, content-script

I have a simple Chrome Extension that logs ids of elements in the console and changes all text element classes to "test".

My `manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Access DOM Example",
  "description": "A script accessing and modifying DOM elements",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "css": ["test.css"],
    "js": ["test.js"],
    "match_about_blank": false,
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "world": "MAIN"
  }]
}
```

and content script, `test.js`:

```js
walk(document.body);

function walk(node) {
    let child, next;

    switch (node.nodeType) {
        case 1:  // Element
        case 9:  // Document
        case 11: // Document fragment
            child = node.firstChild;
            while (child) {
                next = child.nextSibling;
                walk(child);
                child = next;
            }
            break;

        case 3: // Text node
            console.log(node.id);    // shows 'undefined'
            node.className = "test"; // change is never applied, why?
            break;
    }
}
```

Yet for a simple page:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="hello-world">Hello, World!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The script shows 'undefined' in the console and change to class name is not applied.

Is there any way to modify DOM from content script?

Comment: You can modify DOM in the content script by doing it correctly: text nodes don't have `id` or `className`, only elements do. Maybe you could describe in more detail what you mean by "text element". P.S. Don't use `"world": "MAIN"` as it runs in the unsafe context of the web page where your code can be hijacked via prototype spoofing.

Comment: Ahhhhhh THANK YOU, I didn't realize text nodes are not the same thing as elements 